# ASP.NET Microservices - Retrieve Cookie Claims?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, microservices

I have ASP.NET Microservices. The microservice for authentication uses ASP.NET Identity. With it I create Auth Cookie which is successfully shared between the APIs and **I want to use this cookie to authenticate in the other APIs, as well.**

Now this is the tricky part because I cannot properly get (read) the claim information, using the other APIs (in which the ASP.NET Identity is not implemented).

For example, take a look at this screenshot:
[image]

The first section is the Identity/Claims of the HttpContext.User in the API which creates the cookie (and also uses ASP.NET Identity).
The second section is the HttpContext.User from API which **does not use asp.net identity**, but only retrieves the cookie. Apparently, only the username is read (somehow - I did not use any special method, just found it while debugging).

The question is -> Is there a way to read the other claims as well? Especially the roles and the Id. They are of great importance for the other APIs.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to store data protection keys in a shared storage such as Redis or cloud blob storage to have compatible authentication cookies in different applications. That is also necessary if you have a web farm or multiple container instances. Here is a link that shows how to do that.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/implementation/key-storage-providers?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio

You can also configure applications to add additional claims.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/claims?view=aspnetcore-6.0